# Delete Navigation Node with Powershell from SharePoint Quicklaunch in all sites in a site collection

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a `powershell script` to go through all the sub sites in a site collection and remove a node that is no longer required.

I've placed my script below - but I'm getting an error on Get-SPWeb : The pipeline has been stopped - I'm thinking I may need to set a parameter to stop the pipe being closed? Any help is awesome!

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://sitecollurl  

$site | get-spweb -limit all | foreach-object{ 

    $webURL = $_.url 

    $web = Get-SPWeb $webURL 

    $navigationNodes = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch 

    ForEach ($Node in $NavigationNodes) 
    { 
        if($node.Title -eq "My User Profile") 
        { 
        $node.Delete()   
        } 
    } 
   $web.Dispose() 
}
```

Comment: As a resolution I went with a script to iterate through all sites then run a secondary remove script to delete the node. References for the node removal were http://secretsofsharepoint.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2011/07/21/removing-nodes-from-the-quicklaunch.aspx and for the site iteration were http://derbium.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/running-a-script-on-all-sites-in-a-web-application/ - thanks Derbium and Niklas

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue so thought I would share, note in my case it was to remove all QuickLaunch menu Items titled "Libraries" if it had no children:

```
Get-SPSite http://sitecollectionurl | get-spweb -limit all | foreach-object{

$webURL = $_.url 
$web = Get-SPWeb $webURL 
$pubWeb = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($Web)
$qlNav = $pubWeb.Navigation.CurrentNavigationNodes
$qlHeading = $qlNav | where { $_.Title -eq "Libraries" }
$qlLibraries = $qlHeading.Children

if($qlLibraries.Count -eq 0)
{
    $qlHeading.delete()
}
else 
{
    $qlLibraries | Select Title,ID
    $count = $qlLibraries.Count
    write-host "Other Libraries are listed on $url. Count = $count"
}

$pubWeb.Update()
$web.Dispose

}
```

Obviously replace `http://sitecollectionurl` with your own site collection URL, and `libraries` with whatever title you are trying to remove.

Dan